# Why can't I assign a reference to a derived class to a variable if the reference type is a parent class with Generics?

Tags: typescript

Why can't I assign a reference to a derived class to a variable if the reference type is a parent class with Generics?

```
interface IModel {
    id?: number;
}

class Model<T extends IModel> {
    public data: T;
    constructor(data: T) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

interface IConcretModel extends IModel {
    name: string;
}

class ConcretModel extends Model<IConcretModel> {
    static sm1() { }
}

let a: typeof Model;

a = ConcretModel;
```

Error on the last line:

```
Type 'typeof ConcretModel' is not assignable to type 'typeof Model'.
  Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'IConcretModel'.
      Type 'IModel' is not assignable to type 'IConcretModel'.
        Property 'name' is missing in type 'IModel'.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you type a variable as `typeof Model` the class will remain be generic for example you could write :

```
let a: typeof Model;
new a<IConcretModel>(null)
```

As such a non generic class cannot be assigned to the variable. The `typeof` syntax doesn't support specifying the generic parameter to the class so this is not valid `typeof Model<IModel>`.

The simplest workaround is to use a constructor signature instead :

```
let a: new (data: IModel) => Model<IModel>;

a = ConcretModel;
```